# editing a file while in memory during a fresh provisioning?

Tags: linux, bash, vmware, vmware-tools, fsck

I want to disable fsck from doing a file system checks (yes I am aware of it's purpose).  Online it says to edit the 6th column in the /etc/fstab file.

```
sed -i 's/ [1-]$/ 0/g' /etc/fstab
```

I have tried putting it when the kickstarter files run but it doesn't actually edit the file since it is memory.  Am I looking to disabling fsck incorrectly or how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  There are two things that you can do.  For rhel 7 you want to fsck.mode=skip to your boot_opts line.  Then to be able to enable fsck back up, you edit fsck.mode=skip from your grub files then commit those changes to your grub file. grub2-mkconfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg.  This will reactivate the fsck.